# Incorrect data fetched when using file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to fetch a score from an api, i am calling it through a link which requires two inputs. The api compares the two phrase inputs and fetches a score of their similarity. So when i run the link individually ,by pasting it in address bar i get a score. for eg: For link with two inputs as; Introduction to Computers and Computer Science and Programming
    http://swoogle.umbc.edu/SimService/GetSimilarity?operation=api&phrase1=Introduction%20to%20Computers&phrase2=Computer%20Science%20and%20Programming&corpus=Refined%20Stanford%20WebBase%20corpus&type=Relation%20Similarity

I get a score as 0.5055186 , but when i do the same using php code below it fetches me 193849. I am not sure whether it is because of the text to object conversion or some data type error. Below is my code that i am using.

```
<?php

//include('simple_html_dom.php');
 $score = file_get_contents(" http://swoogle.umbc.edu/SimService/GetSimilarity?   operation=api&phrase1=Introduction%20to%20Computers&phrase2=Computer%20Science%20and%20Programming&corpus=Refined%20Stanford%20WebBase%20corpus&type=Relation%20Similarity");

echo $score;

?>
```

Comment: i cut and pasted that and after correcting the whitespace issues in the URL i get the decimal number expected. Is there something else you are not showing?

Comment: Thanks i got it, i used str_replace function to remove the spaces in variables, 

$myi = "The System is back";
 $ini = "The System is back";
 $my = str_replace(" ","%20",$myi);
 $in = str_replace(" ","%20",$ini);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried to run your code below with some changes in URL I see the result 
 0.5055186

```
  <?php

//include('simple_html_dom.php');
 $score = file_get_contents("http://swoogle.umbc.edu/SimService/GetSimilarity?operation=api&phrase1=Introduction%20to%20Computers&phrase2=Computer%20Science%20and%20Programming&corpus=Refined%20Stanford%20WebBase%20corpus&type=Relation%20Similarity");

echo $score;

?>
```

Is this is the requirement?